# How to Redirect a Page on GET URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a page like this `index.php?controller=a&action=b`, but on this page `controller=a` i did nothing, if i access it just a blank page. I need to redirect from `controller=a` to original page `controller=a&action=b`?

Answer (score 0):

What if just check the page url and redirect,

```
if(isset($_GET['controller']) && $_GET['controller'] == "a"){
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: i got this Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by....

Comment: You can't output ANY html BEFORE changing header, so this function should be at the top of the PHP file...

Comment: oh, maybe that's the problem, i have html code before check url, because i use include for my content

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing... i will try my best to help, here's a site that might help you:

https://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Another suggestion that might help in .htaccess is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^controller/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/action/([0-9A-z_-]+)\/$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

this way you might use link www.domain.com/controller/a/action/b/ to access index.php?controller=a&action=b

Comment: I not use htaccess, i dont need it, my problem example: if i go to access url `index.php?controller=a` then redirect to `index.php?controller=a&action=b` because nothing there, and then i also do it to for `index.php` because nothing there too.

Comment: You need to be clearer with the objectives here... you want to check if there is a file in place BEFORE being redirected??

`if (file_exists('index.php')) { header("location: index.php"); }`